# Is there a way to block/filter spoofed emails Office 365/Exchange?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

My company is currently a target of some social engineering attacks where company employees are being sent e-mails from the attacker pretending to be senior members of staff. They have the correct names but are sending the e-mails from random addresses and aren't bothering to hide them.

Whilst technical employees are able to spot these illegitimate e-mails a mile off, I suspect it is only a matter of time before a non-techie falls for them.

An idea we have is to flag any external e-mails from addresses not matching our company addresses so that readers can be wary of the contents of the e-mail, but this isn't particularly ideal.

Is there a way to block external e-mails that do not have a matching e-mail address to their claimed identity?

Comment: Flagging incoming external emails is now pretty standard, Have you looked this up?

Comment: Yes sir, this is something we are looking to implement in the near future. I was looking for some ideas that would address the impersonation attacks directly and automatically in Outlook/Exchange.

Comment: You can't. The name can be anything (like the full name of the person).

Comment: This is what I suspected would be the case. Thanks.

Comment: Be veeeery careful when you flag external messages. When my last company started doing just this, and there were almost immediately several times when legitimate messages, that were generated by internal personnel, marked as "external".  Staff had to send another email telling people it was legit.  So essentially people were quickly trained to ignore the emails with a header marked external.  I should note that to the email systems, the mail WAS external, but they were legit emails, send by upper management through processes IT wasn't aware of.